# Get distance made in a running app Android

Tags: android, gps

I have a question about android, specifically about an action (more like an activity).

I've searched a lot and I can't find anything that I can use.

I'm doing an android application about a running app like runtastic or Garmin run". My application needs 3 things: a Chronometer (which is done and tested), getting the distance which I runned and this is what i need assistance with, and the last its the pace which i ran (I didnt search anything related to it yet so I don't know if i need help too or not).

For now, I need help with the distance, It's not a pedometer, which is all i can find in my search.

My application it is simple. Example of how it works: You leave ur house, and you starting running (you need to press the start button in the android app) and then those 3 things will start, the chronometer, the distance and the pace, the chronometer it is the only thing you can see working if you are in the same place. And when u start running all the 3 things will now counting and it will stop when u press the "stop" button.

My question is, how do i get the distance i ran in the ending of the training.

The distance it isnt like a pedometer, i dont want to know how many steps i did during the training, i want to reach the end of the training and see in my android app for example : 
01:01:45 (represents the timer, in the format HH:MM:SS)
10,51 Km (represents the distance, in the format of quilometers or miles i can see that after)
5,00 Min/Km (represents the pace)

The search that i did, it had 1 possible way that wasnt like a pedometer:
-Or i get 2 points which represents the beginning of the training and the end, and calculate the distance from 1 point to another but if i want to take a shortcut or going training to another point and then return to the final point, it wont add more distance because it is calculated already, if  you understand what I meant.

But, what i really want to my "distance", or at least an idea of it, it is to get the distance by GPS maybe every 5 seconds.
In order to accomplish that, i need to get the location of the device by GPS and every 5 seconds it will get your current location and compare to the last location so that it could calculate the distance and add to the "textView" the distance calculated.

Thanks

Comment: Well just do it then, use the GPS

Comment: You already have the idea for a solution: use the GPS to track location every few seconds. This is likely to be the solution that everyone would suggest. What's the problem?

Comment: How ?? I dont know where to begin doing that, do i search "how to get gps location?" and then "how to get distance made by gps location" ?

Comment: Start by reading the training topic [Making Your App Location-Aware](http://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html).

Comment: its giving me a lot of errors following that guide. :) But the concept that i wanted its there, getting the location and updating it. Im trying to test it, i use Android studio, but maybe its lacking some imports that they didnt show there cause its bugging everywhere